# SQL - Find statement that insert specific values

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm working with an Oracle database, interacting with it both from Oracle SQL Developer and from R. This database is shared between several people, but because of some company rules we all use the same user to interact with it.

In one of our tables we found a strange behaviour, were a line is constantly inserted without any order that we know of.

Say, on Table1, sometimes there is a line with value Name = "Test" created >8K times, and we can't figure out why is this happening.

What I wanted to do is to create some sort of automatism (triger) that, when a line with Name = "Test" is inserted on Table1 saves the query that did it and the date/time.

Comment: Why is there a rule *requiring* shared accounts?  Normally there is a rule *forbidding* shared accounts, to prevent these kinds of situations.

Answer (score 4):

If there are archive logs for the search period. You must use the utility LogMiner. Example 1.

```
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.add_logfile(LOGFILENAME => '/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2/admin/edcu/arc_redo_log/1_39306_769799469.dbf', OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.NEW); 
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.add_logfile(LOGFILENAME => '/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2/admin/edcu/arc_redo_log/1_39307_769799469.dbf', OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.addfile); 
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.add_logfile(LOGFILENAME => '/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2/admin/edcu/arc_redo_log/1_39308_769799469.dbf', OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.addfile); 
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.add_logfile(LOGFILENAME => '/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2/admin/edcu/arc_redo_log/1_39309_769799469.dbf', OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.addfile); 
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.START_LOGMNR(OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.DICT_FROM_ONLINE_CATALOG);

SELECT 
to_char(timestamp,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
operation,username,  
os_username,
machine_name,
session_info,
sql_redo

 FROM v$logmnr_contents
where 
seg_owner='MANAGER' and  seg_name='TEST2'

14-12-2017 09:40:20 DDL     MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  create table test2 (p1 number);
14-12-2017 09:40:47 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1") values (HEXTORAW('c117'));
14-12-2017 09:40:53 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1") values (HEXTORAW('c119'));
14-12-2017 09:40:57 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1") values (HEXTORAW('c137'));
14-12-2017 09:41:01 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1") values (HEXTORAW('c20219'));
14-12-2017 09:41:45 DDL     MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  alter table test2 add (p2 varchar2(200));
14-12-2017 09:42:12 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1","COL 2") values (HEXTORAW('c20219'),HEXTORAW('746573743220746573743120'));
14-12-2017 09:42:24 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1","COL 2") values (HEXTORAW('c2021a'),HEXTORAW('746573743420746573743420'));
14-12-2017 09:46:24 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1","COL 2") values (HEXTORAW('c2021a'),HEXTORAW('746573743420746573743420'));
14-12-2017 09:46:25 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1","COL 2") values (HEXTORAW('c2021a'),HEXTORAW('746573743420746573743420'));
14-12-2017 09:46:26 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1","COL 2") values (HEXTORAW('c2021a'),HEXTORAW('746573743420746573743420'));
14-12-2017 09:46:27 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1","COL 2") values (HEXTORAW('c2021a'),HEXTORAW('746573743420746573743420'));
14-12-2017 09:46:28 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1","COL 2") values (HEXTORAW('c2021a'),HEXTORAW('746573743420746573743420'));
14-12-2017 09:54:37 DDL     MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   comment on table test2 is  'test';
14-12-2017 10:16:36 DDL     MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  alter table test2 add  (p3 varchar2(100));
14-12-2017 10:17:07 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("P1","P2","P3") values ('125','test6','test4 ');
14-12-2017 10:17:08 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("P1","P2","P3") values ('125','test6','test4 ');
'
```

Example 2. Using Flashback Features

```
   update manager.test2 set p2='test10' where p1=125;
    commit;

    SELECT versions_xid XID, versions_startscn START_SCN,
      versions_endscn END_SCN, versions_operation OPERATION,
      p1, p2, p3 FROM manager.test2
    VERSIONS BETWEEN SCN MINVALUE AND MAXVALUE;

XID                                         START_SCN           END_SCN       OPERATION       P1     P2     P3                                                                                                   
---------------------- ------------------------ ---------------------- --------------- ---------- -------- ------
08000E000DD70900        1374388524564                                                 U          125 test10   test4                                                                                                
08000E000DD70900        1374388524564                                                 U          125 test10   test4                                                                                                
08000E000DD70900        1374388524564                                                 U          125 test10                                                                                                            
08000E000DD70900        1374388524564                                                 U          125 test10                                                                                                                       
                                                               1374388524564                     125 test4 test4    
                                                               1374388524564                     125 test4 test4    
                                                               1374388524564                     125 test6 test4 
                                                               1374388524564                     125 test6 test4      



            SELECT  xid, start_scn , commit_scn COMMIT,operation OP, logon_user ,undo_sql FROM flashback_transaction_query
                   WHERE xid = HEXTORAW('08000E000DD70900');

    XID                      START_SCN  COMMIT                OP    LOGON_USER                           UNDO_SQL                                                                                             
-------------------------------- -------------------------------- -------------------------------------- --------------------------------- ------------------------------------                                                        
        08000E000DD70900    1374388524537   1374388524564   UPDATE  MANAGER update "MANAGER"."TEST2" set "P2" = 'test6' where ROWID = 'AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAM';
        08000E000DD70900    1374388524537   1374388524564   UPDATE  MANAGER update "MANAGER"."TEST2" set "P2" = 'test6' where ROWID = 'AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAL';
        08000E000DD70900    1374388524537   1374388524564   UPDATE  MANAGER update "MANAGER"."TEST2" set "P2" = 'test4 test4 ' where ROWID = 'AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAK';
        08000E000DD70900    1374388524537   1374388524564   UPDATE  MANAGER update "MANAGER"."TEST2" set "P2" = 'test4 test4 ' where ROWID = 'AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAJ';
        08000E000DD70900    1374388524537   1374388524564   UPDATE  MANAGER update "MANAGER"."TEST2" set "P2" = 'test4 test4 ' where ROWID = 'AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAI';
        08000E000DD70900    1374388524537   1374388524564   UPDATE  MANAGER update "MANAGER"."TEST2" set "P2" = 'test4 test4 ' where ROWID = 'AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAH';
        08000E000DD70900    1374388524537   1374388524564   UPDATE  MANAGER update "MANAGER"."TEST2" set "P2" = 'test4 test4 ' where ROWID = 'AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAG';
        08000E000DD70900    1374388524537   1374388524564   UPDATE  MANAGER update "MANAGER"."TEST2" set "P2" = 'test4 test4 ' where ROWID = 'AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAF';
        08000E000DD70900    1374388524537   1374388524564   BEGIN   MANAGER
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **audit** feature of the oracle.

```
-- to start auditing on table
AUDIT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON <Schemaname>.<tablename> BY ACCESS WHENEVER SUCCESSFUL;

-- after auditing is started, execute below query to get the audit data
-- Modify the where condition according to your need
SELECT
    OS_USER,
    USERHOST,
    DB_USER,
    TO_CHAR(EXTENDED_TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MON-RRRR HHAM:MI:SS'),
    OBJECT_SCHEMA,
    OBJECT_NAME,
    STATEMENT_TYPE,
    SQL_TEXT,
    SQL_BIND
FROM
    DBA_COMMON_AUDIT_TRAIL
WHERE OBJECT_SCHEMA = <Schemaname>
  AND OBJECT_NAME = <tablename>
ORDER BY
    4 DESC;
```

Auditing options can be set at the database level using the following parameter:

**AUDIT_TRAIL={NONE or FALSE| OS| DB or TRUE| DB_EXTENDED| XML |XML_EXTENDED}**

The following list provides a description of each value:

- NONE or FALSE -> Auditing is disabled. Default until Oracle 10g.
- DB or TRUE -> Auditing is enabled, with all audit records stored in the database audit trail (AUD$). Default from Oracle 11g.
- DB_EXTENDED –> Same as DB, but the SQL_BIND and SQL_TEXT columns are also populated.
- XML-> Auditing is enabled, with all audit records stored as XML format OS files.
- XML_EXTENDED –> Same as XML, but the SQL_BIND and SQL_TEXT columns are also populated.
- OS -> Auditing is enabled, with all audit records directed to the operating system's file specified by AUDIT_FILE_DEST.

Hope, This will be useful to you.

Cheers!!