# Any Log/Audit table in Oracle DB which holds daily transaction details for Audit purpose?

Tags: database, oracle

Need to know about Oracle DB internal Log and Audit tables for daily/any transactions in all tables.

Have consulted with peers if there are any such log and audit tables but of no success. We ended up creating a Stored Proc for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AUDIT` feature of Oracle DB.

Please see my answer in the follwoing question: [SQL - Find statement that insert specific values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56647258/sql-find-statement-that-insert-specific-values/56647916#56647916)

For more details regarding auditing, Please follow the Oracle documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4007.htm

Feel free to ask in comments, if you have any doubts.

Cheers!!