# How can i get the queries executed on a particular table in database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I wanted to find the queries that were executed on a particular table in database

Let me know the query...through which I can fetch the queries that were executed on a particular table

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AUDIT` feature of Oracle DB as concrete and customized solution.

Please see my answer in the following question: [SQL - Find statement that insert specific values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56647258/sql-find-statement-that-insert-specific-values/56647916#56647916)

For more details regarding auditing, Please follow the Oracle documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4007.htm

Feel free to ask in comments, if you have any doubts.

Cheers!!