# Oracle database rollback

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

I accidentally used *imp* instead of *exp* which replaced my database with a very old backup. My oracle version is 9i. Any help to get the data back.

Comment: Restore a physical backup and use the archived logs to roll forward to a point just before the `imp`.  But I'm guessing you don't have a physical backup and/or archived logs.  Do you only have logical backups from previous exports?  If so, you can probably only restore the last logical backup and all the changes since then are lost.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56647258/sql-find-statement-that-insert-specific-values  Try to take information from archive logs if archive logs are not overwritten. https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/logminer-enhancements-9i