# How to debug which DB user made changes on a table due to which indexes of the table became unusable in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I faced an issue wherein indexes of all my table became unusable , I want to debug the cause of this .
Currently I have rebuilt all the indexes but I don't know the root cause of this , How to find out what changes were made on the table and by which DB user ?

Comment: You may want to learn the meaning of the word "debug", if you plan to use it. It doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56647258/sql-find-statement-that-insert-specific-values/56647490#56647490

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up how indexes become unusable - a normal insert won't do that. One of the following more than likely happened:

- A direct-path load took place resulted in duplicate data for a unique index.
- The physical location of the table’s data changed during an operation, such as table reorganization.
- someone manually altered the indexes.

See here:

- https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-C44AADF7-777D-4847-A5ED-75E36B40D0EB.htm#SUTIL1305
- https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:1859798300346695894
- https://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3735286/Oracle-Unusable-Indexes.htm

Tracking down *who* or *what* caused this will depend on what level of auditing you have enabled on your database. If you weren't auditing for DDL operations at a minimum, you may never be able to say for sure.